# Moving custom library build to other machine of similar architecture

Tags: embedded-linux, setup-deployment, nvidia-jetson, prebuild

I am currently setting up a microcontroller with several libraries which need to be built from source. Using pre-built binaries is not an option due to the system architecture. Building dependencies takes a lot of time and I want to avoid having to do it again for every similar device I need to setup in the future.

Thus, my question is, how can I migrate custom built binaries to another machine of similar architecture?

Any solution that would mirror the whole system to another drive works, too.

Note: For my current use case I am running Ubuntu 18.04 off a MicroSD plugged into a Jetson Nano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any solution that would mirror the whole system to another drive works, too.

Proposed Solution :

1. Create a backup of the MicroSD card which has all required binaries installed
2. Use the backup to mirror the stuff into different MicroSD cards.

#### Backing Up Your SD card

1. Connect the SDcard to your laptop
2. Use dd command to take a backup of your MicroSD card

```sh
sudo dd if=/dev/sdxx of=backup.img status=progress
```

#### Restoring your backup to a New SD Card

1. Connect the New SDcard to your laptop
2. Use dd command to restore the backup to New MicroSD card

```sh
sudo dd if=backup.img of=/dev/sdxx status=progress
```

**Note**: Your SD card may also show up as `/dev/mmcxx` or `/dev/sdxx` depending on how you connect it to your laptop.

**Warning**: While running `dd` command, Please make sure that `/dev/sdxx` is your SD card and not your Hard Disk.
Running this command will tell you the device name of your SD card.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Please refer to this [link](https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/how-to-back-up-your-raspberry-pi-project-files) for more.